# Can keras progress bar show instantaneous metrics rather than running average?

Tags: keras

By "progress bar" I mean the standard progress bar that shows up with `tf.keras.Model.fit`

As I understand, it shows a running average of your selected metrics (over the current epoch), but I want it to show the value at the last completed iteration.

Is there a built-in way to make this change? And if not, what would be the easiest way?

Comment: do u mean verbose=2 ?

Comment: I don't think so. That will show a bar for each epoch without replacing the original one. But the metric shown in the progress bar parameters will still be a running average.

Answer (score 0):

I made a callback a while ago to solve this problem.

```
class print_on_end(Callback):
  def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    print()
```

You want to call it like this.

```
model.fit(training_dataset, steps_per_epoch=num_training_samples, epochs=EPOCHS,validation_data=validation_dataset, callbacks=[print_on_end()])
```

But this callback prints the everages, just on different lines, so i don't thinks its what you want.

This instead:

```
class LossAndErrorPrintingCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        print("For batch {}, loss is {:7.2f}.".format(batch, logs["loss"]))
            )
        )
```

This callback prints the loss of every batch, so it should be what you are looking for.

( if you need the metric just change `logs["loss"]` with `logs["name of the metric"]`  ex. `logs["mean_absolute_error"]`

EDIT:

to check the name of the metric inside logs you could print the keys of the log and find the ona you are searching.

```
class PrintKeys(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print(keys)
            )
        )
```

In that method you should only find the keys for the loss and the metric.

source:
https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/

Comment: But keep in mind that this callback will make a mess with the real output of fit, so consider putting fit on quiet mode, or just write the callback output on a text file

Comment: Thanks for this, yes I definitely wanted to avoid that sort of mess and do want to have metrics in the progress bar itself. I tired to use the `stateful_metrcis` argument of `ProgbarLogger` but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: sorry, i never got my hands dirty with the progress bar itself, all the data that i consider meaningful is always printed on external files

Answer (score 0):

An example of the class hierarchy of the MeanSquaredError metric is

```
MeanSquaredError->MeanMetricWrapper->Mean->Reduce->Metric
```

> Is there a built-in way ?

The main problem is that all metrics are subclasses of the Reduce metric, which performs the aggregation, and there is nothing foreseen to change the behaviour of the Reduce base class.

> How to achieve this the most easily

Given the schema above  you can achieve what you want by means of creating a new metric subclass of the MeanMetricWrapper
which overrides the update_state method of the MeanMetricWrapper
by means of first calling `self.reset_state` and then  `MeanMetricWrapper.update_state`.
Like this, the aggregates in the underlying Reduce base class will aggregate only a single value. Working Example below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.metrics import MeanMetricWrapper

x=np.linspace(0, 1, 20000)[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
y=np.sin(x*2*np.pi)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="tanh", input_shape=(1,1)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="tanh"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4))

#####
# Here the Instantaneous metric variant 
class InstMetric(MeanMetricWrapper):
    def __init__(self, fn, **kwargs):
        """ fn is the callable loss function you want to use in your metric """
        super().__init__(fn=fn, **kwargs)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        self.reset_states()
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
#####

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=[
                 keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(name="MSE"),
                 InstMetric(keras.metrics.mean_squared_error, name="IMSE")
              ]
)

model.fit(x=x, y=y, epochs=1, batch_size=5, steps_per_epoch=1000)
```

Storing this script as inst_demo.py and running it through `tr` to unfold the progress bar in the terminal
you get

```
$> ./inst_demo.py | tr \\r \\n 

   1/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 8:07 - loss: 0.4656 - MSE: 0.4656 - IMSE: 0.4656
  42/1000 [>.............................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4874 - MSE: 0.4874 - IMSE: 0.4133  
  87/1000 [=>............................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4685 - MSE: 0.4685 - IMSE: 0.4764
 132/1000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4627 - MSE: 0.4627 - IMSE: 0.5445
 175/1000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4558 - MSE: 0.4558 - IMSE: 0.7689
 217/1000 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4443 - MSE: 0.4443 - IMSE: 0.1058
 264/1000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4258 - MSE: 0.4258 - IMSE: 0.4162
 311/1000 [========>.....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4090 - MSE: 0.4090 - IMSE: 0.1716
 356/1000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3889 - MSE: 0.3889 - IMSE: 0.3417
 400/1000 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3707 - MSE: 0.3707 - IMSE: 0.1271
 445/1000 [============>.................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3532 - MSE: 0.3532 - IMSE: 0.0729
 489/1000 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3383 - MSE: 0.3383 - IMSE: 0.2310
 535/1000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3248 - MSE: 0.3248 - IMSE: 0.1228
 580/1000 [================>.............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3143 - MSE: 0.3143 - IMSE: 0.2670
 625/1000 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3048 - MSE: 0.3048 - IMSE: 0.1762
 671/1000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2962 - MSE: 0.2962 - IMSE: 0.0751
 715/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2896 - MSE: 0.2896 - IMSE: 0.0650
 756/1000 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2831 - MSE: 0.2831 - IMSE: 0.2332
 799/1000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2773 - MSE: 0.2773 - IMSE: 0.1026
 841/1000 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2721 - MSE: 0.2721 - IMSE: 0.1238
 888/1000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2673 - MSE: 0.2673 - IMSE: 0.1471
 936/1000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2631 - MSE: 0.2631 - IMSE: 0.2242
 986/1000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2580 - MSE: 0.2580 - IMSE: 0.2704
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2574 - MSE: 0.2574 - IMSE: 0.2773
```

So you get an instant value each time the progressbar is updated.

You can also derive the InstMetric from any of the available keras metrics, if you don't want to be able to select the metric you will use.